# Formatting date stored in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, date, formatting

I'm querying a database and echoing the "date" column using PHP.

The date is displaying as YYYY-MM-DD, as it is saved under the "date" data type.

Which function would be best suited to convert the date structure to "Sunday 25th May 2013"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

$phpmyadmindatevalue is the value from the date column in your database.

```
<?php 

   $date = date("l jS F Y", strtotime($phpmyadmindatevalue));
   echo $date;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php
echo date("l jS F Y", strtotime($value));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it helps you

```
$mydate = "2013-03-24";

$mytime = strtotime($mydate);

echo date("l jS \of F Y ",$mytime);
```